# Seqelize: Retrieve latest of hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is my relationship:

```
KbDevice.hasMany(KbDeviceEvent, { foreignKey: 'kb_device_id', as: 'events' })
```

Here is my query:

```
  const allKbDevice = await KbDevice.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'make', 'model'],
    include: [
      {
        model: KbDeviceEvent,
        as: 'events',
        attributes: ['id', 'event', 'chamber_id','created_at'],
      },
    ],
  });
```

The issue is, instead of an array, I would like to get **one** `KbDeviceEvent` as the latest item based on `created_at`. I tried to use an `include` but it kept throwing an error. Can anyone help please?

Do you need to see the actual models to answer this question? If so, please comment.

Thank you,

EDIT:

Here is the result of the above query:

```
{
  "id": "d75f9f96-a468-4c95-8098-a92411f8e73c",
  "make": "Toyota",
  "model": "Lexus",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "a737bf7b-2b2e-4817-b351-69db330cb5c7",
      "event": "deposit",
      "chamber_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2022-09-01T22:36:19.849Z"
    },
  ]
}
```

And I'm looking for:

```
{
  "id": "d75f9f96-a468-4c95-8098-a92411f8e73c",
  "make": "Toyota",
  "model": "Lexus",
  "event": { // I am the latest event
    "id": "a737bf7b-2b2e-4817-b351-69db330cb5c7",
    "event": "deposit",
    "chamber_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T22:36:19.849Z"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query to fetch the associated model sorted by `created_at`:

```
const allKbDevice = await KbDevice.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'make', 'model'],
    include: [
      {
        model: KbDeviceEvent,
        as: 'events',
        attributes: ['id', 'event', 'chamber_id','created_at'],
      },
    ],
    order: [
      [{ model: KbDeviceEvent, as: 'events' }, 'created_at', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit: 1
});
```

Please note that this will always return the results in this manner:

```
{
  "id": "d75f9f96-a468-4c95-8098-a92411f8e73c",
  "make": "Toyota",
  "model": "Lexus",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "a737bf7b-2b2e-4817-b351-69db330cb5c7",
      "event": "deposit",
      "chamber_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2022-09-01T22:36:19.849Z"
    },
  ]
}
```

since `KbDevice` model has `hasMany` relation with `KbDeviceEvent` model. You can do `allKbDevice['events'][0]` in your code to get the single event. If you are open to modifying the query, then you can achieve an output which doesn't have any array. However, `device` would be embedded inside `event` object. The query would be:

```
const kbDeviceEvent = await KbDeviceEvent.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'event', 'chamber_id','created_at'],
    order: [
      ['created_at', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit: 1,
    include: [
      {
        model: KbDevice,
        as: 'device',
        attributes: ['id', 'make', 'model']
      },
    ]
});
```

This will output something like this:

```
{
  "id": "a737bf7b-2b2e-4817-b351-69db330cb5c7",
  "event": "deposit",
  "chamber_id": 2,
  "created_at": "2022-09-01T22:36:19.849Z"
  "device": {
    "id": "d75f9f96-a468-4c95-8098-a92411f8e73c",
    "make": "Toyota",
    "model": "Lexus",
  }
}
```